# problems in 3D reconstruction by triangulation opencv

Tags: opencv, 3d, triangulation

I'm currently working in an stereo vision project, in which I'm supposed to reconstruct 3D points from correspondences found in each camera view, and for that I'm using OpenCV 2.4.7 for C++.

I was able to correctly calibrate both cameras, compute fundamental matrix, compute re-projection matrix and also rectify images.

My problem lies on the final part of the project, which is compute 3D world coordinates from 2D point correspondences. I already tried using cv::triangulatePoints, but the results where points with coordinates (0, 0, 0), no matter what the input points were. I also tried the linear triangulation algorithm by Hartley & Strum, but that didn't give me good results either.

Could somebody give me a hint on what function I should use? Or maybe some tips on how to correctly implement the ones I've talked about. My biggest problem is to find good documentation on the internet, so that's why I decided to ask here.

Thank you!

Comment: You might be passing wrong input to the `triangulatePoints` method. Check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295551/how-to-correctly-use-cvtriangulatepoints

Answer (score 0):

I tried cv::triangulatePoints also and it calculates garbage. I was forced to implement a linear triangulation method manually, which returns the triangulated 3D point given a stereo pixel correspondence:

```
Mat triangulate_Linear_LS(Mat mat_P_l, Mat mat_P_r, Mat warped_back_l, Mat warped_back_r)
{
    Mat A(4,3,CV_64FC1), b(4,1,CV_64FC1), X(3,1,CV_64FC1), X_homogeneous(4,1,CV_64FC1), W(1,1,CV_64FC1);
    W.at<double>(0,0) = 1.0;
    A.at<double>(0,0) = (warped_back_l.at<double>(0,0)/warped_back_l.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_l.at<double>(2,0) - mat_P_l.at<double>(0,0);
    A.at<double>(0,1) = (warped_back_l.at<double>(0,0)/warped_back_l.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_l.at<double>(2,1) - mat_P_l.at<double>(0,1);
    A.at<double>(0,2) = (warped_back_l.at<double>(0,0)/warped_back_l.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_l.at<double>(2,2) - mat_P_l.at<double>(0,2);
    A.at<double>(1,0) = (warped_back_l.at<double>(1,0)/warped_back_l.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_l.at<double>(2,0) - mat_P_l.at<double>(1,0);
    A.at<double>(1,1) = (warped_back_l.at<double>(1,0)/warped_back_l.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_l.at<double>(2,1) - mat_P_l.at<double>(1,1);
    A.at<double>(1,2) = (warped_back_l.at<double>(1,0)/warped_back_l.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_l.at<double>(2,2) - mat_P_l.at<double>(1,2);
    A.at<double>(2,0) = (warped_back_r.at<double>(0,0)/warped_back_r.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_r.at<double>(2,0) - mat_P_r.at<double>(0,0);
    A.at<double>(2,1) = (warped_back_r.at<double>(0,0)/warped_back_r.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_r.at<double>(2,1) - mat_P_r.at<double>(0,1);
    A.at<double>(2,2) = (warped_back_r.at<double>(0,0)/warped_back_r.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_r.at<double>(2,2) - mat_P_r.at<double>(0,2);
    A.at<double>(3,0) = (warped_back_r.at<double>(1,0)/warped_back_r.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_r.at<double>(2,0) - mat_P_r.at<double>(1,0);
    A.at<double>(3,1) = (warped_back_r.at<double>(1,0)/warped_back_r.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_r.at<double>(2,1) - mat_P_r.at<double>(1,1);
    A.at<double>(3,2) = (warped_back_r.at<double>(1,0)/warped_back_r.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_r.at<double>(2,2) - mat_P_r.at<double>(1,2);
    b.at<double>(0,0) = -((warped_back_l.at<double>(0,0)/warped_back_l.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_l.at<double>(2,3) - mat_P_l.at<double>(0,3));
    b.at<double>(1,0) = -((warped_back_l.at<double>(1,0)/warped_back_l.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_l.at<double>(2,3) - mat_P_l.at<double>(1,3));
    b.at<double>(2,0) = -((warped_back_r.at<double>(0,0)/warped_back_r.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_r.at<double>(2,3) - mat_P_r.at<double>(0,3));
    b.at<double>(3,0) = -((warped_back_r.at<double>(1,0)/warped_back_r.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_r.at<double>(2,3) - mat_P_r.at<double>(1,3));
    solve(A,b,X,DECOMP_SVD);
    vconcat(X,W,X_homogeneous);
    return X_homogeneous;
}
```

the input parameters are two 3x4 camera projection matrices and the left/right corresponding homogeneous pixel coordinates.

Comment: do yourself a favour, and use `Mat_<double>` for this kind of adventure, you then can skip the `at<double>` part, and access is e.g. a nice `b(1,0)` . huge gain in readability/clarity

Comment: I'll try it out some day

Comment: Would you explain please, why for example in `(warped_back_r.at<double>(1,0)/warped_back_r.at<double>(2,0))*mat_P_r.at<double>(2,3) - mat_P_r.at<double>(1,3)` r(1,0) divided by r(2,0)*P(2,3)?

Comment: The algorithm is linear triangulation (for reference read chapter 12.2 of free online book "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision" by Andrew Zissermann). The idea is to infer X in the equation x=PX with x as pixel coordinates, P as camera matrix and X as space coordinates. Since the left and right term are equal their cross product is zero which can be reshaped as AX=0. The above method solves this equation after creating A from x and P.